# How to make a SlideBar(TrackBar) that have two handles(needles)

Tags: c#, windows, custom-controls

My Question is that i have to make a SlideBar(TrackBar) that have two handles(needles)

**1- Minmum(Lower Value)
2- Maximum(Upper Value)**

Like:

**Start <------------------||--------------------------||------------------------>End**
In fact may required range is two long about 2000 ticks onto slidebar. so far I have searched on the internet and i found an example of Slidebar at code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28717/A-custom-range-selector-control-in-C-with-a-little
it has the option that we add range values from XML file but for two long values its range values are overlapped and a straight line can bee seen.As I am newbie to C# and No idea to develop Custom Controls.

Any suggestion would be very thankful.

Comment: You have two options:
1) Create your new SlideBar by extending the UserControl base class. Here you have to do all the pixel low level work yourself.
2) Create you new SlideBar by combining existing controls into a new control. e. use two buttons with left and right images for the left and right buttons, use two buttons for the moving buttons and one container panel that hosts them all. Here you don't have to do any low level pixel painting.

An entyr link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w29y3h59(v=vs.80).aspx