# Adding Two TrackBar to UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, trackbar

I am working TrackBars, I have to add two TrackBars in a single UserControl in parallel, so I can use them one as for "Low Value" and second as for "High Value".

I have asked the similar question,below is the link:

[How to make a SlideBar(TrackBar) that have two handles(needles)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16197686/1147352)

I am attaching an image below which I started designing, I have added tooltips as well but now I am stuck on how to override or add extra features to take values from both of the Trackbars into separate TextBoxes/Labels etc, and also bound them not to overlap each other means, Min(Low) won't exceed the Max(High)
[image]